# Ruby: Use variable as range in step loop

Tags: ruby, loops

I have the following loop:

```
(10..30).step(10) do |i|
   #do something
END
```

This works well, but I would like to use a variable to define the `10..30` range to have something like this:

```
if something == foo
  range = '10..30'
else
  range = '40..60'
end
(range).step(10) do |i|
   #do something
END
```

However, this code does not run. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Is the assignment of `something = foo` on purpose, or is that supposed to be a comparison (`something == foo`)?

Comment: *This works well* ? how? Your working code is also missing `do` keyword.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code has to be syntactically correct before we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not wrap range definition in quotes. In quotes, you defines strings, not ranges. Instead write:

```
if something == foo
  range = 10..30
else
  range = 40..60
end
range.step(10) do |i|
   #do something
end
```

(also fixed some other minor issues with this snippet).

Comment: As a bonus you can omit the `range =` part and just chain off the `end` of the `if`.